# Separation of romantic and sexual attraction

Tags: sexuality, physical-attraction, love, attraction

Occasionally I meet people who say that they are sexually attracted to X group of people (e.g. men) and romantically attracted to Y group of people, X and Y not being the same (Sometimes they overlap, e.g. a bisexual person who is only romantically attracted to people of the opposite gender,but sometimes not at all). Recently I got into an argument with a friend about to what extent this viewpoint (i.e. to what extent such separation is real vs. imagined) is supported by professional researchers and by hard data.

I found a variety of old articles regarding distinguishing between the different neurological and evolutionary bases for these being different separate systems:

- (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019888024255) Defining the Brain Systems of Lust, Romantic Attraction, and Attachment
- (https://psycnet.apa.org/buy/1986-21992-001) A triangular theory of love.

and a couple articles from Lisa Diamond which specifically address whether these two modes of attraction can diverge:

- (http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/0033-295X.110.1.173) What does sexual orientation orient? A biobehavioral model distinguishing romantic love and sexual desire.
- (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.0963-7214.2004.00287.x) Emerging Perspectives on Distinctions Between Romantic Love and Sexual Desire

In the lattermost article, Diamond argues in the abstract "not only can humans experience these feelings separately, but an individual's sexual predisposition for the same sex, the other sex, or both sexes may not circumscribe his or her capacity to fall in love with partners of either gender."

Diamond's work, being the work most directly addressing the question, seems to give a pretty direct answer - yes, this separation a real thing. The articles are *very* highly cited, making me think that this viewpoint is viewed favorably throughout the field.

However, my friend is not convinced and demands further evidence. I've had trouble finding more research or data that follows up on this topic one way or another. Is there more recent research or data on this question that follows up or supports Diamond's work? Diamond herself admits that she doesn't have much hard-data to draw upon at the time (over 15 years ago).